# How to add the data from document users to document orders using usersID?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to list orders in a table. However I have the userId embedded in the orders documents{orderItemss, orderTotal, shippingFee,userID}, and not the user's name, email, contact, etc.

How do I dynamically get the user fName, lName, etc to join OrderDetails and display the full object within a table?

[image]

WHat i tried was:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../utils/firebase";

const Orders = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
    const ordersCollectRef = query(collection(db, "Orders"));
    const userCollectionRef = query(collection(db, "User"));
    useEffect(() => {
        const getUsers = async () => {
            const data = await getDocs(userCollectionRef);
            setUsers(
                data.docs.map((doc) => ({
                    ...doc.data(),
                    id: doc.id,
                }))
            );
        };
        getUsers();
        const getOrders = async () => {
            const orderData = await getDocs(ordersCollectRef);

            setOrders(
                orderData.docs.map((order) => ({
                    ...order.data(),
                }))
            );
        };
        getOrders();
    }, []);
```

....

```
<table className="table-auto w-full text-base text-left text-gray-900">
                    <thead className="text-sm text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-50">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">
                                First
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">
                                Last Name
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">
                                Contact
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">
                                Address
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">
                                Order Total
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">
                                Shipping Fee
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">
                                Grand Total
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">
                                Actions
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {orders.map((order, i) => (
                            <tr className="bg-white border-b" key={i}>
                                <th
                                    scope="row"
                                    className="py-4 px-6 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap"
                                >
                                    {/* {user.fName} */}
                                </th>
                                <td></td>
                                <td className="py-4 px-6">{/* {user.lName} */}</td>
                                <td className="py-4 px-6">
                                    {/* {user.contact.primary
                                        ? user.contact.primary
                                        : user.contact.secondary} */}
                                </td>
                                {/* <td className="py-4 px-6">
                                    {user.shippingAddress.street},<br />
                                    {user.shippingAddress.parish}
                                </td> */}
                                <td className="py-4 px-6">{order.orderTotal}</td>
                                <td className="py-4 px-6">{order.shippingFee}</td>
                                <td className="py-4 px-6">{order.grandTotal}</td>
                                <td className="py-4 px-6  items-center  justify-center flex space-x-2 text-white font-medium font-serif">
                                    <button className="w-16 h-8 rounded-md bg-blue-500">
                                        {" "}
                                        edit
                                    </button>{" "}
                                    <button className="w-16 h-8 rounded-md bg-red-500">
                                        delete
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

i honestly havent made an attempt to join the objects/lists. Every approach I think of is flaud from the beginning[image]

Comment: found what I am asking here at https://youtu.be/35RlydUf6xo?t=497 . However still having a bit of challenge breaking it down

Comment: What is the challenge that you are facing?

Comment: @HittuDesai I am unable to join orderdetails documents and users documents the firebase way. I want to output a table listing in each row the order and the user information of the order, instead of listing the user ID.

Comment: @HittuDesai i tried something like this, ya it doesnt work. But how far off am i?    const getOrders = async () => {
   const orderData = await getDocs(ordersCollectRef);
   const orderDocs = orderData.docs.map((order) =>
    {...order.data(),getDoc(db, "User", order.userId)}
   );
   setOrders(orderDocs);
  };
  getOrders();

Comment: Wait, so all you want is, that the orders given by a particular user are stored inside the user object you get from firestore?

Comment: @HittuDesai I want to join orders and user details(fname, lname, address) so that I can show the user and the order is the same table row. Currently orders -> only have userId

Comment: I think I got a way to do this, I will add a long answer suggesting some changes on how you can do this by making slight additions to your already existing code

Comment: But before that, I understand you want details of the orders linked to their corresponding user data. Now that can be done with your currently existing code, but would be a tad bit difficult. Or it can be done by making small changes to the handler when an order is submitted by a user. What would you prefer?

Comment: @HittuDesai hey I already implemented the submit handler, submitted the order with userId. The issue is looping over all orders in the database, and finding the user details that matches all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to combine the data from two collections then you have to do it in javascript. I'm not really sure what you want to achieve but here's my take how you will combine the data based from the userID field. See code below:

```
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
  const ordersCollectRef = query(collection(db, "Orders"));
  const userCollectionRef = query(collection(db, "User"));
  useEffect(() => {
      const getOrders = async () => {
        const orderData = await getDocs(ordersCollectRef);
        const usersData = await getDocs(userCollectionRef);
        const combinedData = [];
        var users = usersData.docs.map((doc) => ({
          ...doc.data(),
          id: doc.id,
        }))

        var orders = orderData.docs.map((order) => ({
            ...order.data(),
        }))

        orders.forEach((order) => {
          users.forEach((user) => {
            if (order.userID == user.id) {
              combinedData.push({...order, user})
            }
          })
        })
        // console.log(combinedData)
        
        setOrders(
          combinedData
        );
      };
      getOrders();
  }, []);
```

Rendering:

```
<table className="table-auto w-full text-base text-left text-gray-900">
    <thead className="text-sm text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-50">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">
                First
            </th>
            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">
                Last Name
            </th>
            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">
                Contact
            </th>
            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">
                Address
            </th>
            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">
                Order Total
            </th>
            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">
                Shipping Fee
            </th>
            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">
                Grand Total
            </th>
            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">
                Actions
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {orders.map((order, i) => (
            <tr className="bg-white border-b" key={i}>
                <th
                    scope="row"
                    className="py-4 px-6 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap"
                >
                    {order.user.fName}
                </th>
                <td className="py-4 px-6">{order.user.lName}</td>
                <td className="py-4 px-6">
                    {order.user.contact.primary
                        ? order.user.contact.primary
                        : order.user.contact.secondary}
                </td>
                <td className="py-4 px-6">
                    {order.user.shippingAddress.street},<br />
                    {order.user.shippingAddress.parish}
                </td>
                <td className="py-4 px-6">{order.user.fName}</td>
                <td className="py-4 px-6">{order.shippingFee}</td>
                <td className="py-4 px-6">{order.grandTotal}</td>
                <td className="py-4 px-6  items-center  justify-center flex space-x-2 text-white font-medium font-serif">
                    <button className="w-16 h-8 rounded-md bg-blue-500">
                        {" "}
                        edit
                    </button>{" "}
                    <button className="w-16 h-8 rounded-md bg-red-500">
                        delete
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        ))}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Result:
[image]

***Note: There are many ways to combine objects, this is just one of them.***

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Revised Answer

To attach user details to each order, you can do the following:

```
const [combinedData, setCombinedData] = useState([]);

for(const order in orders) {
    const userID = order.userID;
    const userData = users.filter(user => user.userID === userID)
    const orderCopy = { ...order, ...userData };
    setCombinedData([ ...combinedData, orderCopy ]);
}
```

---

There are two ways of going about it. The more efficient way is as follows:

In your submit order handler, after you create an order document using addDoc(), you can store the id of the newly created document as an element in the orders array of the user document corresponding to the currently logged in user. That way, when you want to display the orders of a user, you only need to fetch those documents whose id is mentioned inside the orders array.

If you want to work with fetching all users and all orders at the same time, you will have to do it inside a useEffect call, with dependencies as [users, orders] with the following callback:

```
if(users.length === 0 && orders.length === 0) return; // return if run before fetching

for(const user in users) {
    const userID = user.id;
    const ordersByUser = orders.filter(order => order.userID === userID);
    // Make a new array of the users with details of their orders here using another state variable
}
```

Let me know if you need help with more code.

Comment: hey @hittudesai a step to the answer doing  ->  const o = orderData.docs.map((order) => ({
    ...order.data(),
    userD: getU(["mazLfmqTRG0huVlLj65C"]),
   }));
   setOrders(o);

Only thing I enter the id of a user manually, and just need now to loop through the spread data

Comment: So, I assume, your problem's solved?

Comment: lol no. I tried the way you showed, but wasnt getting a result, but it lead me to this approach. So thanks for that. However adding a getDoc function with the userId as a parameter while mapping the rows, returned a """ Promise {<fulfilled>: {…}} """ with the details in it. So its a step closer

Comment: If you wanna map by orders, I will add the entire code regarding that at the top of my original answer.